# How Java chooses a garbage collector in a container environment

Tags: kubernetes, jvm

When I was learning about garbage collection recently, I saw a statement that if the machine deploying the application is 1C, it is recommended to use SerialGC, otherwise it is recommended to use G1.

So I was thinking, if I deploy my Java application to kubernetes, and the CPU of Node in Kubernetes is 16C and the CPU of Pod is 1C, if my Java application does not have -XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:+ enabled UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap, my Java application should think it is on 16C, but in reality it only has 1 in 16 CPU time per CPU, so in this case, should I choose SerialGC or G1?

Comment: The recommendation for SerialGC is based on the implicit assumption that throughput is all that matters to you. However, maybe low pause times are more important to you or you want to benefit from String deduplication. In either of these cases, G1GC would be the better choice, even when running with a single CPU core.

Comment: @Holger If I am a single core and go to use G1, it will also open multiple threads to do the work, right? Doesn't this increase the context switching of threads?

Comment: You will never run without thread switching in real life. That’s nothing to worry about. On the plus side, a concurrent garbage collector may utilize the CPU when your application thread is waiting for I/O.